# Select first 'N' elements from map in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there an elegant method of extracting first 'N' elements from a Map ?

I could create a new Map and iterate over the values that are to be selected, is there a function that accomplishes this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map) for the `take` method on `Map`:

> Selects first *n* elements.
>
> Note: might return different results for different runs, unless the
>   underlying collection type is ordered.

In the case of maps the collection isn't ordered, so don't count on getting *the* first *n* elements—in fact the concept of *the* first *n* elements doesn't even exist for maps.

But `take` will give you *some* first *n* elements, and it sounds like this is what you want:

```
scala> Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3).take(2)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2)
```

In this case you happen to get the two elements that came first in the definition, but don't count on this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a [`SortedMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap), along with `take(n)` as discussed by others.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val map = Map[String,Int]("one"->1,"two"->2,"three"->3)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = 
                           Map(one -> 1, two -> 2, three -> 3)

scala> val n = 2
n: Int = 2

scala> val firstN = map.take(n)
firstN: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)
```